# Does libcypher-parser has support for REGEX operator?

Tags: cypher

I'm trying to parse a Cypher query that uses the `=~` regex operator, but I get an error when trying to use libcypher-parser.

I've tried to parse the query found in the Neo4J documentation:

```
WITH ['mouse', 'chair', 'door', 'house'] AS wordlist
UNWIND wordlist AS word
WITH word
WHERE word =~ '.*ous.*'
RETURN word
```

It can be found here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-a-regular-expression-to-filter-words

I tried this command:

```
echo "WITH ['mouse', 'chair', 'door', 'house'] AS wordlist UNWIND wordlist AS word WITH word WHERE word =~ '.*ous.*' RETURN word" | cypher-lint -a
```

I get this error:

```
<stdin>:1:100: Invalid input '~': expected NOT, '+', '-', TRUE, FALSE, NULL, "...string...", a float, an integer, '[', a parameter, '{', CASE, FILTER, EXTRACT, REDUCE, ALL, ANY, NONE, SINGLE, shortestPath, allShortestPaths, '(', a function name or an identifier
...ordlist UNWIND wordlist AS word WITH word WHERE word =~ '.*ous.*' RETURN word
                                                         ^
```

Is it really not supported? What version of the libcypher-parser should I use that supports the `=~` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in libcypher-parser prior to version 0.6.0. It should be resolved in later releases.